# PostgreSQL: Creating case insensitive database supporting three languages (Arabic, English and French)

Tags: c#, postgresql, xpo

I am using **PostgreSQL 15**
01-Is it possible to change the case insensitive of a database after it has been created without losing data (using Collations)
[image]
02-How can I be creating case insensitive database (using Collations) that supports three languages (Arabic, English and French)

Comment: which character set and collation do you have at this time? Besides crate a n ew database copy all data and see iif other character set collation work for you

Comment: In my current database I have English and French I wanted to change it to be case insensitive

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/291281 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191905/

Comment: at the end of the manual page you find that you have to amke your own collation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html

Comment: @nbk let's say I going with this option CREATE COLLATION case_insensitive (provider = icu, locale = 'und-u-ks-level2', deterministic = false) does this supports supports three languages (Arabic, English and French)

Comment: you will have to test it